# Import from ms access to sql server 2008

Tags: import, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

Following [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/transferring-data-ms-access-2003-to-sql-server-2008) article I am importing data of **ms access** to **sql server**.

On the importing time the process has stopped at the point of 84% as shown in below image.

[image: Sql server Import Export Wizard]

The process is not going away. I think its happen because the access DB is a large file, about **350MB**, but not sure...

Comment: Leave it as it is, you having a very large data so, there will be some time taken to import. If I am not wrong than there must be a large record near to 5000 or more...

Comment: Is the process still using HDD and CPU? If so I'd agree, wait it out.

Comment: I had waited for half an hour. Till how much I have to wait....????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave, it as it is. And wait because you having so much data, and there will be long time is gonna to import then.

See for long distance travel, we need more time same as for large amount of data to import we need more time.

So, wait I am sure the data will be import successfully....